# How to increase the runtime of a background task?

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

so I have a Background task on UWP that downloads data from a server. This task may take up to a minute depending on internet speeds. I found that when my user minimised the app the download was paused, so decided to run it on a [BackgroundTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks)

When testing I found my download was not finishing and later found from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) that background tasks have a limitation:

> Background tasks are limited to 30 seconds of wall-clock usage.

But after some more googling I found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly) which speaks of a way to increase the timeout of a background task

> In the Universal Windows Platform, background tasks are processes that
>   run in the background without any form of user interface. Background
>   tasks may generally run for a maximum of twenty-five seconds before
>   they are cancelled. Some of the longer-running tasks also have a check
>   to ensure that the background task is not sitting idle or using
>   memory. In the in the Windows Creators Update (version 1703), the
>   extendedBackgroundTaskTime restricted capability was introduced to
>   remove these limits. The extendedBackgroundTaskTime capability is
>   added as a restricted capability in your app's manifest file:
>
> Package.appxmanifest
>
> XML
>
> ```
>  <Package ...> 
>     <Capabilities>  
>         <rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime"/>      
>     </Capabilities> 
>   </Package>
> ```
>
> This capability removes execution time
>   limitations and the idle task watchdog

But after adding the above to my package.appxmanifest file I get the following error:

> Content of the file 'Package.appxmanifest' is not well-formed XML.
>   'rescap' is an undeclared prefix

So is it possible to remove this background task limitation from my app?

Comment: Read the links in that article you found, especially [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I can see it says "No one may request access to these capabilities for store submission." under the `extendedBackgroundTaskTime`. does this mean its not possible to do what I'm trying to do above?

Comment: I have no idea. I just read that you were getting the error about rescap, knew it as a basic XML namespace validation thing, and read enough of the article to see where they add the namespace.

Comment: Are you sure you squeezed it correctly into the file?

Comment: Background downloader https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader

Comment: Also this article specifies for long term download https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-File-Downloader-a9946bc9  and documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike McCaughan observes in the comments on the question, the most likely explanation for the specific error you are seeing is that you simply have not declared the `rescap` namespace on the enclosing **Package** element that is being referenced by the capability tag:

```
<Package
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
    xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
    xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp wincap rescap">
```

Whether you need the other namespaces or not I cannot say, but the key one involved in the restricted capabilities case you are contending with is the one for `xmlns:rescap`.

Information taken from the [documentation provided by Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities).

Answer (score 2):

UWP has a feature that allows you to queue downloads that can finish even when the app is closed.
Look at [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33313.uwp-background-transfers.aspx) which explains how to use this feature.

If you still want to start the download from the background task, then make the background task call that feature and this way, when the background task expires the download will continue and will be managed by Windows and UWP.